# Classes Using their Own Getters/Setters

Tags: c++, class, getter

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:

    int Data;

    public:

    MyClass(int Init)
    {
        Data = Init;
    }

    int GetData() const
    {
        return Data;
    }
};
```

Now, let's say I want to add a method that checks if `Data` is equal to zero.  There are two ways to accomplish this:

```
bool DataIsZero() const
{
    return Data == 0;
}
```

Or:

```
bool DataIsZero() const
{
    return GetData() == 0;
}
```

Which is considered better practice?  I can see how just using the variable itself might improve readability, but using the getter might make the code easier to maintain.

Comment: A stylistic note is that you should have your member functions in lowercase.  Capitalization is generally reserved for static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I don't really like getters/setters for reasons that I won't go into here. They're covered in other questions. However, since you've asked about them, my answer will assume that I use getters/setters; it will not visit all the possible alternatives.*

I'd use the getter, for the maintenance reasons to which you allude. Indeed, the abstraction is half the purpose of having the getter in the first place (along with the slightly tighter access control).

If using the variable is more legible than using the getter, then your getter function name is poor and should be reconsidered.

As an aside, it's best to initialise members, not assign them in your constructor body after the fact. In fact, you *have* to do that with constants, so you might as well start now and remain consistent:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int Data;

public:

    MyClass(int Init) : Data(Init) {}

    int GetData() const {
        return Data;
    }
};
```

See how the constructor has changed.

Comment: The *getter* should be used since when the code to get the value changes, all methods that directly access the member must change also.  Maintenance nightmare.  Also, many compilers will inline simple getters and setters so the work is on the typist (programmer).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Or, in other words, "I'd use the getter, for the maintenance reasons to which you allude". :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the getter, because if your class moves to a more complex logic in the getter, then you will be insulated from the change. However, if your class provides a public getter, I'd question the logic of creating this method.

Comment: Regarding your second sentence, whilst I don't necessarily disagree with you, it might be worth noting two things: (a) the OP's example *may* be a simplified, contrived code sample; the actual use case may be less contrived; (b) `std::string::empty()` is rather nice to have, even though it's really easy to compare `std::string::length()` to `0`. So sometimes there is a rationale for making member functions that might otherwise seem a little pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

The former is sufficient for simple classes.

The latter hides the implementation and can support polymorphism, if the method is virtual.